# How to read the list element and store the value in another element of the same list based on conditional check using a stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have the below sample code. I want to read the values from the elements in the List and add in another element of the same List with conditional check.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties
class MyItems {
    private List<GroupItemInfo> groupItemInfos;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public static class Details {
        private String id;
        private String status;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public static class GroupItemInfo {
        private String type;
        List<Details> items;
    }
}

public class ScreenTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<MyItems.GroupItemInfo> itemInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyItems.GroupItemInfo groupItemInfo1 = new MyItems.GroupItemInfo();
        groupItemInfo1.setType(null);
        groupItemInfo1.setItems(null);

        MyItems.GroupItemInfo groupItemInfo2 = new MyItems.GroupItemInfo();
        List<MyItems.Details> detailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyItems.Details details1 = new MyItems.Details();
        details1.setId("A");
        details1.setStatus("Active");
        MyItems.Details details2 = new MyItems.Details();
        details2.setId("B");
        details2.setStatus("Active");
        MyItems.Details details3 = new MyItems.Details();
        details3.setId("C");
        details3.setStatus("InActive");
        detailsList.add(details1);
        detailsList.add(details2);
        detailsList.add(details3);

        groupItemInfo2.setType("WIRE");
        groupItemInfo2.setItems(detailsList);


        MyItems.GroupItemInfo groupItemInfo3 = new MyItems.GroupItemInfo();
        MyItems.Details details4= new MyItems.Details();
        details4.setId("A");
        details4.setStatus("Active");
        MyItems.Details details5 = new MyItems.Details();
        details5.setId("H");
        details5.setStatus("Active");
        List<MyItems.Details> detailsList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        detailsList2.add(details4);
        detailsList2.add(details5);
        groupItemInfo3.setType("MODEM");
        groupItemInfo3.setItems(detailsList2);

        itemInfoList.add(groupItemInfo1);
        itemInfoList.add(groupItemInfo2);
        itemInfoList.add(groupItemInfo3);
        System.out.println("---------itemInfoList------------ " + itemInfoList);

      /*  itemInfoList.stream().forEach(groupItemInfo -> {
            groupItemInfo.setType();
        });*/
    }
}
```

I want to store all the items from all objects whose `type!=null` (WIRE,MODEM) in the object with `type=null` and should be unique (duplicates should not be allowed).
Below is the sample image of how the data is stored.

[image]

In the above image, the result list has 3 elements and element 2 and element 3 has items that I wanted to read and store in the first element whose `type==null` (without duplicates).
Having difficulty in how to read the groupItemInfo.getItems() when already in the loop(itemsList.stream().forEach..).

Expectation is for element zero with type=null and items=null, read all the items from other elements in the list and store with out duplicates (A,B,C,H should be stored)

---EDITED---

Showing error when tried the code as shown in the below image
[image]

Comment: If the answers resolved your question please mark them as answer, that's how SO community works..

Answer (score 0):

Since lombok is already generating `equals/hashCode` for you this should be very simple.

```
List<MyItems.Details> combined = Stream.concat(detailsList.stream(), detailsList2.stream()) // Create a Stream based on the two lists
    .distinct() // Remove duplicates
    .toList(); // Creates the list. Depending on your Java version you may need to write collect(Collectors.toList()) instead.
groupItemInfo1.setItems(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only unique elements, I would suggest you change the type of the `items` member of `GroupItemInfo` from `List<Details>` to `Set<Details>` (or `SortedSet<Details>` if an ordering is needed).

Similarly, you might want to think if you really need the `itemInfoList` member to be a `List<MyItems.GroupItemInfo>` or can it be a `Set<MyItems.GroupItemInfo>` instead (or again a `SortedSet<MyItems.GroupItemInfo>` depending on the ordering need).

Now having said that, with the above code (assuming you can't change) we can do this as below,

```
// First get the one whose type==null..
MyItems.GroupItemInfo nullTypedGroupItemInfo = itemInfoList.stream().filter(groupItemInfo -> groupItemInfo.getType() == null).findFirst().orElseThrow();

// Get unique, ordered set of details from the others whose whose type!=null..
Collection<Details> detailsCollection = itemInfoList.stream().filter(groupItemInfo -> groupItemInfo.getType() != null).flatMap(item -> item.getItems().stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet<Details>::new));
});

// Finally set the above unique details collection in the one whose type==null that we obtained earlier..
nullTypedGroupItemInfo.setItems(new ArrayList<>(detailsCollection));
```

Comment: @Imk - when trying the above code, it is showing  error " no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that List<Details> conforms to Stream<? extends R> " near line filter(groupItemInfo -> groupItemInfo.getType() != null)

Comment: @user8115347 i have updated the code fragment, basically the compiler can't figure out the generic type automatically so we need to explicitly specify...i am just typing the code  fragment & not using an editor...so didn't catch it. Please look at the updated code fragment.

Comment: @user8115347 Btw, please accept/upvote if it answers your question..

Comment: still it is giving the same error. Please see the edited post above, i have added the  image which shows the code you had suggested and error message.

Comment: @user8115347 Now i see the cause, thanks to the image...I missed returning a stream in the `flatMap` invocation since i was typing it freely in the box & not in an editor. Fixed that in the answer. Now it should work!

Comment: Please take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap\(java.util.function.Function\)), so it will help you better understand the code, ..good luck!

Comment: @user8115347 So did it work & solved ur question?